# React Query with custom hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks, react-query

I'm building a web app fetching data from a `strapi` CMS. I made a custom hook with `useQuery` for data fetching. Strangely, when I use the hook, the parent component's style briefly switches from `none` to `block` after data retrieval. But this doesn't happen if I directly use `useQuery` in the component.

code so far:

```
const useCollectionHook = (props: {
  page: number;
  pageSize: string;
  type: COLLECTIONS;
  modelClass: any;
  searchTerm?: string;
}) => {
  const pageKey = `collection-${props.type}`;
  const { data, isLoading, error, isFetching, isSuccess, refetch } =
    useQuery<ICollectionPageProps>({
      queryKey: [pageKey, props.searchTerm, props.page],
      queryFn: () => {
        return getCollectionPageData(
          props.type,
          props.pageSize,
          props.modelClass,
          props.page,
          props.searchTerm,
        );
      },
      enabled: false,
      staleTime: 5 * 1000,
      suspense:true
    });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    refetch();
  }, [props.searchTerm, props.page, refetch]);

  return { data, isLoading, error, isFetching, isSuccess };
};



export default function BlogsCollectionSection(
  props: Readonly<ICollectionSectionProps>
) {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const searchTerm = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.ui.searchTerm);
  const { data, isLoading, error, isFetching, isSuccess } = useCollectionHook({
    type: props.data.type,
    pageSize: props.data.pageSize,
    page: currentPage,
    modelClass: (MODEL_MAPPING as any)[props.data.type],
    searchTerm: searchTerm,
  });

  return (
    <div className="min-h-[300px]">
    ....
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Side note: why are you calling refetch in an effect? The api will be called again when anything in the query key changes.

Comment: where are you using `none` or `block`

Comment: Yeah you're using useQuery wrong. You really shouldn't need to be doing the refetch in the useEffect here